# An urn of 4 balls with 2 colors. Pick 2 balls and place them back 4 times. What's the probability of picking 2 balls of the same color twice in a row?

Tags: probability

An urn of 4 balls with 2 colors. Pick 2 balls and place them back 4 times. What's the probability of picking 2 balls of the same color twice in a row?

So the probability of picking 2 balls of the same color is $2\choose1$$2\choose2$/$4\choose2$, but I don't know the probability of getting that twice in a row out of 4 draws

Comment: You say the urn has 2 colors, but not the distribution of the colors among the balls. If two are red and two are green, there is a $\dfrac{1}{3}$ chance of picking two balls of the same color. If three are red and one is green, there is a $\dfrac{1}{2}$ chance of picking two balls of the same color. Also, when you say picking "2 balls of the same color twice in a row", does that mean picking two green followed by two red counts? Or must you pick two green twice in a row or two red twice in a row?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assumptions:

1. There are two balls of one color and two balls of a second color
2. Suppose the colors are Green and Red. A successful outcome occurs in any of these cases when you choose two green followed by two green, two green followed by two red, two red followed by two green, or two red followed by two red.

The probability of picking two balls of the same color in a single draw is as you found $\dfrac{1}{3}$. A single draw will be labeled $S$ for both balls are the same color and $D$ for the balls are different colors. Here are the possible outcomes:

$$\begin{array}{c|c|c}\text{Draws} & \text{Probability} & \text{2-in-a-row?} \\ \hline DDDD & \left(\dfrac{2}{3}\right)^4\left(\dfrac{1}{3}\right)^0 & \text{No} \\ DDDS & \left(\dfrac{2}{3}\right)^3\left(\dfrac{1}{3}\right)^1 & \text{No} \\ DDSD & \left(\dfrac{2}{3}\right)^3\left(\dfrac{1}{3}\right)^1 & \text{No} \\ DDSS & \left(\dfrac{2}{3}\right)^2\left(\dfrac{1}{3}\right)^2 & \text{Yes} \\ DSDD & \left(\dfrac{2}{3}\right)^3\left(\dfrac{1}{3}\right)^1 & \text{No} \\ DSDS & \left(\dfrac{2}{3}\right)^2\left(\dfrac{1}{3}\right)^2 & \text{No} \\ DSSD & \left(\dfrac{2}{3}\right)^2\left(\dfrac{1}{3}\right)^2 & \text{Yes} \\ DSSS & \left(\dfrac{2}{3}\right)^1\left(\dfrac{1}{3}\right)^3 & \text{Yes} \\ SDDD & \left(\dfrac{2}{3}\right)^3\left(\dfrac{1}{3}\right)^1 & \text{No} \\ SDDS & \left(\dfrac{2}{3}\right)^2\left(\dfrac{1}{3}\right)^2 & \text{No} \\ SDSD & \left(\dfrac{2}{3}\right)^2\left(\dfrac{1}{3}\right)^2 & \text{No} \\ SDSS & \left(\dfrac{2}{3}\right)^1\left(\dfrac{1}{3}\right)^3 & \text{Yes} \\ SSDD & \left(\dfrac{2}{3}\right)^2\left(\dfrac{1}{3}\right)^2 & \text{Yes} \\ SSDS & \left(\dfrac{2}{3}\right)^1\left(\dfrac{1}{3}\right)^3 & \text{Yes} \\ SSSD & \left(\dfrac{2}{3}\right)^1\left(\dfrac{1}{3}\right)^3 & \text{Yes} \\ SSSS & \left(\dfrac{2}{3}\right)^0\left(\dfrac{1}{3}\right)^4 & \text{Yes}\end{array}$$

Adding this up, I get:
$$3\left(\dfrac{2}{3}\right)^2\left(\dfrac{1}{3}\right)^2+4\left(\dfrac{2}{3}\right)^1\left(\dfrac{1}{3}\right)^3+\left(\dfrac{2}{3}\right)^0\left(\dfrac{1}{3}\right)^4 = \dfrac{7}{27}$$

Comment: +1 You can shortcut this a bit, but it's the right way to do it.